# Binding to changes on global variable in electron

Tags: node.js, electron, ractivejs

For an electron-app I use a global variable to store some constantly changing values in my administration panel (mainly status information received from various clients).

So in my main process I collect this data and write it to a variable

```
global.sharedObject = {
    Clients:[]
}
//on receiving information via ipc
global.sharedObject.Clients.push(data);
```

this works flawless, and gives me a array of Objects with my client status data. For example `[{"id":"abe289c8-71ae-4764-87d8-1eb7b8adde7f","IP":"192.168.0.2","type":"Client Type 1","MachineName":"HP4711"}]`

In my renderer process there is a page where this data is displayed live via ractive:

```
const remote = require('electron').remote;
let ClientList = remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').Clients;
let ractive = new Ractive({
    el: '#clientBoxes',
    template: myTemplate,
    twoway: false,
    //magic: true,
    data: {
        Clients: ClientList //or with same result:
        Clients: remote.getGlobal('sharedObject').Clients;
    });
```

The data is rendered correct, but only updates if I reload the page. If I use `magic: true`I get a error `TypeError: Cannot redefine property: id
    at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
    at ...\ractive\ractive.js:10637:11`

Has anyone got an idea, or knows a better way to store rapidly changing values globally in electron?

Answer (score 2):

[Documentation](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md) for `remote` says:

> Note: Arrays and Buffers are copied over IPC when accessed via the remote module. Modifying them in the renderer process does not modify them in the main process and vice versa.

This means that when you call `remote.getGlobal('sharedObject')` you just get the state of `shareObject` at that moment in time. Your view doesn't update because the array simply didn't change on the renderer side.

You could just send a message via `win.webContents.send` every time `shareObject` gets updated. In the renderer you listen for those messages and then just update the reactive component.

Comment: Oh dang. Did not see this one. Thanks. I thought of webContents before, but my app is no single page application, so maintaining constantly changing data over multiple pages (only one of them is using this data) is quite an overload. Therefore I was hoping I could store it somehow globally (the local Storage would be also possible, but this data is time-relevant and should not be persisted in case the application crashes or shuts down).